# UIAWrapper returns incorrect rectangle for window

Tags: python, pywinauto, win32gui

I was trying to get all the running processes and want to display it as small snapshot images in a list. I was able to do that. But for one of my applications (A winforms application developed in C#), it does not work as expected. I can clearly see the application is running and visible.

```
 windows = Desktop(backend='uia').windows()
 for win in windows:
    print(win.element_info.rectangle)
```

Here the rectangle gives me `<RECT L0, T0, R0, B0>` for the above mentioned application.
When I tried to get the window rectangle using the window handle, there also I am not getting the correct value.

```
left, top, right, bot = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
```

This gives me values as follows.

```
left : -40000
top: -40000
right:-39751
bot: - 39957
```

What could be wrong here? I have only one window in that application. It works for all other windows (explorer, outlook, chrome, edge, VS Code etc)

Answer (score 0):

If even Win32 API OS function gets wrong data, It's something wrong with the window itself on the app side. Please report it to the app developers. There is nothing to do on Python side.